# How do buffers work? and why only solutions of a weak acid and its salt with a strong base or vice versa work as a buffer

Tags: physical-chemistry, buffer

Please note that the definition of a buffer in my textbook is given as

> The solutions which resist change in pH on dilution or with the addition of small amounts of acid and alkali are called Buffer Solutions

Is this the right explanation of a buffer?
If not what is the right explanation?

Comment: In contrary to some other Q/A or forum sites, answers on CH SE site are figuratively paid by the user's own effort. When you ask, it is expected you have already searched for and thoroughly thought about the topic, providing explicit compact summary of partial answers or at least ideas or thoughts you have got until then. Effort not shown may be considered as effort not done and such a question may be closed.  [How do I ask a good question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

pH basically means "how much of $\ce{H+}$ there is in the solution". And the job of the buffer is to keep this concentration more or less constant: if someone "consumed" $\ce{H+}$ our buffer has to generate new $\ce{H+}$; and if someone produced $\ce{H+}$, our buffer needs to "consume" the extra amount.

Suppose you have a solution with $\mathrm{pH=4}$ and you add a weak acid (let's call it $\ce{HA}$) with approximately the same $\mathrm{pK_a=4}$. Because $\mathrm{pH=pK_a}$ half of that $\ce{HA}$ substance will be dissociated into anion ($\ce{A-}$) and $\ce{H+}$ and the other half will stay intact as $\ce{HA}$. But if something changed the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution, then the proportions of Dissociated:Intact versions of the molecule would shift.

So if we then try adding another acid which is stronger ($\mathrm{pK_a=2}$):

1. We'll get an excess of $\ce{H+}$ from that new acid
2. And those extra $\ce{H+}$ will be consumed by the original $\ce{A-}$ turning it back to $\ce{HA}$. Therefore $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution will stay approximately the same.

If we add a base ($\mathrm{pK_a=6}$):

1. Those $\ce{H+}$ that left the original $\ce{HA}$ will be consumed by that base
2. Which means the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ drops, but this in turn leads to our original $\ce{HA}$ dissociating further producing more $\ce{A-}$ and $\ce{H+}$

Therefore $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution again stays more or less the same. Here are some video explanations of [Acid-Base equilibrium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5fk7HPmo5g) and [Buffer Solutions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIvEvwViJGk).